# what is repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process on eclipse console android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Working with `developer phone` earlier,  today i tried my hand on emulator i do not know why its showing

```
repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
```

in `console window` with every application i am trying to Run.

Thanks

Yasir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the Application on an emulator without GPU emulation ? Go to AVD manager, edit the hardware properties of your emulator . Disable gpu emulation and see if the application runs now.